# How to check if a string only contains certain characters in scala

Tags: regex, scala

How to check whether a string **only** contains certain characters, say "a" and "b" in Scala?
I found several resources online, they are using regex.
For Scala, most of them talked about the findAllIn or findFirstIn function. But I would like to have something that returns true or false.

Comment: `findFirstIn` returns an Option that you can use, but why not use contains?

Comment: @Thefourthbird because contains allows other characters to be in the string as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val s: String = ???

s.forall("ab".contains)
```

`forall` checks whether a condition is true for all elements of a collection. So in this case it checks whether a condition is true for each character in `s`.

`contains` checks whether a string contains a character, so `"ab".contains(x)` checks whether `x` is either 'a' or 'b'.

Comment: This works as well! But is using findFirstIn (check whether it returns None) or forall a better way? perhaps which method is faster?

Comment: `forall` is arguably more idiomatic and likely to be faster for a simple check like this. `findFirstIn` might be more appropriate if the test was more complicated.

Comment: I would use a `Set[Char]` instead of a `String` for the `contains`.

Comment: For me `s.forall("ab".contains)` did not work. I had to modify the solution as `s.forall("ab".contains(_))`.

Comment: @Quiescent Yes, the answer works for Scala 3 but Scala 2 does need the solution you gave.